# What applications are on my Droid phone?

Tags: android

Is there a way to programmatically determine what applications are on my Droid phone?

Is there an API I can call?

Answer (score 1):

The `PackageManger` class has a [`getInstalledApplications(int flags)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29) method and a [`getInstalledPackages(int flags)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29). One (possibly both) of those will most likely give you what you want.